# Scheduled method won't execute when I make a Spring bean to Application Scope

Tags: spring, scheduling, application-scope

```java
@Service
@ApplicationScope
public class TestService {

        @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
        @SchedulerLock(name = "TEST-SERVICE", lockAtLeastForString = "PT10S", lockAtMostForString =       "PT20S")
        public void testJob(){
              System.out.println("TEST-SERVICE " + LocalDateTime.now() +Thread.currentThread().getName());
        
       }

}
```

I have added @EnableScheduling to my spring application as well. The code will start working as soon as remove the @ApplicationScope annotation. My application is deployed on multiple nodes on a weblogic server and the scheduled method is invoked twice, that's the reason I need my bean to be application.

Either I have to avoid my code executing twice, or I have to make my scheduled code to run in the cluster.